# Nullable types: better way to check for null or zero in c#

Tags: c#, null, zero

I'm working on a project where i find i'm checking for the following in many, many places:

```
if(item.Rate == 0 || item.Rate == null) { }
```

more as a curiousity than anything, what's the best way to check for both cases?

I've added a helper method which is:

```
public static bool nz(object obj)
{
    var parsedInt = 0;
    var parsed = int.TryParse(obj.ToString(), out parsedInt);
    return IsNull(obj) || (parsed && parsedInt == 0);
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

I like `if ((item.Rate ?? 0) == 0) { }`

**Update 1:**

You could also define an extension method like:

```
public static bool IsNullOrValue(this double? value, double valueToCheck)
{
    return (value??valueToCheck) == valueToCheck;
}
```

And use it like this:

`if(item.IsNullOrValue(0)){}`   // but you don't get much from it

Comment: thank you - very succinct! i was concerned with the readability, but came to the conclusion that it would be perfectly readable had I actually understood the ?? operator.

Comment: You should use the extension method; while it is readable at the moment of writing, this little code nuggets requires a fraction of thought, meaning if you try to read code and it uses it - you are distracted from your main problem.

Comment: @configurator: as it stands, i'd need an extension method for each nullable property of Item - that doesn't seem like the best solution

Comment: @nailitdown That was a quick extension method that works, but you can expand on it using generic ... personally I stick to the operator, because it is also supported on linq2sql :)

Comment: @nailitdown: not really, you just need an extension method for Nullable<T>. double? is an alias for Nullable<double>. Your signature will look like: public static bool IsNullOrValue<T>(this Nullable<T>, t valueToCheck) where T : struct

Comment: @nailitdown: (part II) Your return statement would then look like
return (value ?? default(T)).Equals(valueToCheck);

Comment: If you shortened it to "IsNullOr(0)" it would naturally read as "is null or zero"

Comment: `public static bool IsNullOrValue<T>(this T? value, T valueToCheck) where T : struct
{
 return (value ?? default(T)).Equals(valueToCheck);
}`

Comment: I just want to pile on and provide this same solution in the context of ADO.Net (since this is how I found this thread):
cmdADO.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XyzID", ((theObj.XyzID ?? 0) != 0) ? (object)theObj.XyzID : DBNull.Value);

Answer (score 61):

Although I quite like the accepted answer, I think that, for completeness, this option should be mentioned as well:

```
if (item.Rate.GetValueOrDefault() == 0) { }
```

This solution

- does not require an additional method,
- is faster than all the other options, since [GetValueOrDefault is a single field read operation](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/)¹ and
- reads easier than `((item.Rate ?? 0) == 0)` (this might be a matter of taste, though).

---

¹ This should not influence your decision, though, since these kinds of micro-optimization are unlikely to make any difference.

Answer (score 46):

Using generics:

```
static bool IsNullOrDefault<T>(T value)
{
    return object.Equals(value, default(T));
}

//...
double d = 0;
IsNullOrDefault(d); // true
MyClass c = null;
IsNullOrDefault(c); // true
```

If `T` it's a *reference type*, `value` will be compared with `null` ( `default(T)` ), otherwise, if `T` is a `value type`, let's say double, `default(t)` is 0d, for bool is `false`, for char is `'\0'` and so on...

Comment: extension method:
`public static bool IsNullOrValue<T>(this T? value, T valueToCheck) where T : struct
{
 return (value ?? default(T)).Equals(valueToCheck);
}`

Comment: I love the cleanness of this solution.  Keep in mind `default(int?)` is `null` and not `0` however..  All nullable value(integral numeric) types default value is null and will return false if passed 0 in this method.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values

Answer (score 32):

C#9 : you can write

```
if (item.Rate is null or 0)
```

Comment: To me, this looks a whole lot better and more readable than any ?? solution

Answer (score 20):

This is really just an expansion of Freddy Rios' accepted answer only using Generics.

```
public static bool IsNullOrDefault<T>(this Nullable<T> value) where T : struct
{
    return default(T).Equals( value.GetValueOrDefault() );
}

public static bool IsValue<T>(this Nullable<T> value, T valueToCheck) where T : struct
{
    return valueToCheck.Equals((value ?? valueToCheck));
}
```

**NOTE** we don't need to check default(T) for null since we are dealing with either value types or structs! This also means we can safely assume T valueToCheck will not be null; Remember here that T? is shorthand Nullable<T> so by adding the extension to Nullable<T> we get the method in int?, double?, bool? etc.

**Examples:**

```
double? x = null;
x.IsNullOrDefault(); //true

int? y = 3;
y.IsNullOrDefault(); //false

bool? z = false;
z.IsNullOrDefault(); //true
```

Answer (score 3):

Using C# 7.0 or later you could use the `is` keyword to match objects against a pattern like this: (see [is operator - C# reference | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is))

```
if (item is { Rate: 0 or null })
{
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: This answer, or something very similar, has already been posted by Eric Bole-Feysot

Comment: In C# 7.3 I get error CS8370

Answer (score 2):

I agree with using the ?? operator.

If you're dealing with strings use if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(myStr))

Answer (score 2):

You code sample will fail. If obj is null then the obj.ToString() will result in a null reference exception. I'd short cut the process and check for a null obj at the start of your helper function. As to your actual question, what's the type you're checking for null or zero? On String there's a great IsNullOrEmpty function, seems to me this would be a great use of extension methods to implement an IsNullOrZero method on the int? type.

Edit: Remember, the '?' is just compiler sugar for the INullable type, so you could probably take an INullable as the parm and then jsut compare it to null (parm == null) and if not null compare to zero.

Comment: cheers for catching that bug - in this project i need to check against int?, double?, decimal?, etc. which is why i'm using "object"

Comment: Remember, the '?' is just compiler sugar for the INullable<T> type, so you could probably take an INullable<T> as the parm and then jsut compare it to null (parm == null) and if not null compare to zero.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a better way?

Well, if you are really looking for a better way, you can probably add another layer of abstraction on top of Rate. 
Well here is something I just came up with using Nullable Design Pattern.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NullObjectPatternTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var items = new List
                            {
                                new Item(RateFactory.Create(20)),
                                new Item(RateFactory.Create(null))
                            };

            PrintPricesForItems(items);
        }

        private static void PrintPricesForItems(IEnumerable items)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
                Console.WriteLine("Item Price: {0:C}", item.GetPrice());
        }
    }

    public abstract class ItemBase
    {
        public abstract Rate Rate { get; }
        public int GetPrice()
        {
            // There is NO need to check if Rate == 0 or Rate == null
            return 1 * Rate.Value;
        }
    }

    public class Item : ItemBase
    {
        private readonly Rate _Rate;
        public override Rate Rate { get { return _Rate; } }
        public Item(Rate rate) { _Rate = rate; }
    }

    public sealed class RateFactory
    {
        public static Rate Create(int? rateValue)
        {
            if (!rateValue || rateValue == 0) 
                return new NullRate();
            return new Rate(rateValue);
        }
    }

    public class Rate
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public virtual bool HasValue { get { return (Value > 0); } }
        public Rate(int value) { Value = value; }
    }

    public class NullRate : Rate
    {
        public override bool HasValue { get { return false; } }
        public NullRate() : base(0) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you're right that eliminating null values at some earlier stage would've been the way to go

Comment: Not exactly.  There is a concept called "Refactoring".  You can refactor your code toward a better pattern or to a better structure.  You can always *eliminate* nullable values at later stages.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool nz(object obj)
{
    return obj == null || obj.Equals(Activator.CreateInstance(obj.GetType()));
}
```

Comment: Reflection is *slow*, be careful with solutions like this. I don't object to reflection, but I wouldn't expect it in a "simple" function like this and it would catch me off guard.

Comment: does this actually check for zero?

Comment: Actually, no. Activator.CreateInstance(obj.GetType()) will return null for nullable types, I believe.

Comment: @configurator: when nullable types are boxed, they're boxed as the underlying struct, i.e., so this will not construct a null-values nullable, but a default-valued non-nullable struct.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Item{  
 bool IsNullOrZero{ get{return ((this.Rate ?? 0) == 0);}}
}
```

Comment: your solution works for one property, i should've specified i have many properties of the same item to check for null/zero

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget, for strings, you can always use:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)
```

Instead of:

```
str==null || str==""
```

Comment: Question compares against "0" not an empty string.

Answer (score -1):

One step further from [Joshua Shannon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69077/joshua-shannon)'s nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/633514/3095779). Now with preventing [boxing/unboxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing):

```
public static class NullableEx
{
    public static bool IsNullOrDefault<T>(this T? value)
        where T : struct
    {
        return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value.GetValueOrDefault(), default(T));
    }
}
```