# Is there any difference between myNullableLong.HasValue and myNullableLong != null?

Tags: c#, nullable

When I have a nullable long, for example, is there any difference between

```
myNullableLong.HasValue
```

and

```
myNullableLong != null
```

... or is it just 'syntactic sugar'?

Comment: See this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676078/which-is-preferred-nullable-hasvalue-or-nullable-null)

Comment: It's about readbility only.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It's just syntactic sugar. They will behave exactly the same way - the nullity test actually gets compiled into a call to `HasValue` anyway.

Sample:

```
public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int? x = 0;
        bool y = x.HasValue;
        bool z = x != null;
    }
}
```

IL:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       25 (0x19)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init (valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32> V_0)
  IL_0000:  ldloca.s   V_0
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0003:  call       instance void valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::.ctor(!0)
  IL_0008:  ldloca.s   V_0
  IL_000a:  call       instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::get_HasValue()
  IL_000f:  pop
  IL_0010:  ldloca.s   V_0
  IL_0012:  call       instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::get_HasValue()
  IL_0017:  pop
  IL_0018:  ret
} // end of method Test::Main
```

Comment: Which of the two would you consider 'neater'?

Comment: @Neil: It depends on the context. I would probably *usually* use the null comparison, but occasionally I guess `HasValue` would be more readable.

Comment: Thanks.  I have to say that I see more `!= null` than I do `HasValue` comparisons.

Comment: That's as I suspected. This question arose when I was asked in a code review to change my use of != null to HasValue, and I was questioning why...

Comment: I know this is old, but was wondering the answer to this. I prefer `!= null` personally. I guess it would make sense though based on Jon's answer to prefer `HasValue` if `!= null` is compiled to a call to `HasValue` in any case, though, compilers are fast enough right... so it's basically a subjective choice. I'll stick to `!= null` personally :)

Comment: I wonder if this holds true in Linq-To-Entities.  I can see how it could equate these two when explicitly comparing to null, but what about comparing two nullable field like so: `Where( x => true && (x.t1.NullableField == x.t2.NullableField)).  In TSQL, such a comparison would fail if both fields are null, unless it explicitly injects an 'or both are null' check.

Answer (score 8):

It's syntactic sugar; `Nullable<T>` is actually a `struct`, so it cannot *actually* be `null`; the compiler turns calls that compare to `null` (like your second example) into calls to `HasValue`.

Note, though, that boxing a `Nullable<T>` into an `object` will result in either the value of `T` (if it has a value) or `null` (if it doesn't).

I.E.

```
int? foo = 10; // Nullable<int> with a value of 10 and HasValue = true
int? bar = null; // Nullable<int> with a value of 0 and HasValue = false

object fooObj = foo; // boxes the int 10
object barObj = bar; // boxes null

Console.WriteLine(fooObj.GetType()) // System.Int32
Console.WriteLine(barObj.GetType()) // NullReferenceException
```

Answer (score 3):

No.

The C# compiler has built-in support for `Nullable<T>` and will turn equality operations involving `null` into calls to the struct's members.

`n != null` and `n.HasValue` will both compile to identical IL.