# No DateTime?.ToString(string) overload?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am aware of the standard procedure for displaying a `DateTime` in a custom format, like so:

`MessageBox.Show(dateSent.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));`

However, when I change the variable from a `DateTime` to a `DateTime?` to accept null values, I lose the definition for the `ToString(string)` overload. I need to use `DateTime?` as I am reading from a database which potentially has null values - if the field in the database has a null value, then I need to assign the variable a null value too.

So I have two questions:

1) Out of curiosity, does anyone know if there is a reason why `DateTime?` does not contain an overload for `ToString(string)`?

2) Could anyone suggest an alternative method for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Because it could possibly be null. What is `null.ToString()`?

Comment: `Because it could possibly be null.` is not a rhetorical question. The actual question is not rhetorical either. If you can tell me what null.ToString() I think it would very helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I format a nullable DateTime with ToString()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833054/how-can-i-format-a-nullable-datetime-with-tostring)

Comment: @JoelEtherton - null.ToString() yields a compilation error because you need to call .ToString() on something where the type is inferrable, and null is not that.  I think what you meant is what is x.ToString() when x is an unassigned DateTime?, in which case it calls the struct's ToString() method which returns empty string since the value is null.

Comment: @user420667: I know the difference. The question was delivered to get OP to consider the concept more thoroughly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DateTime?` is syntactic sugar for [`Nullable<DateTime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) and that's why it don't have `ToString(format)` overload.

However, you can access underlying `DateTime` struct using `Value` property. But before that use `HasValue` to check, if the value exists.

```
MessageBox.Show(dateSent.HasValue ? dateSent.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss") : string.Empty)
```

Comment: Apparently `DateTime` does not contain a definition for `HasValue`?

Comment: But `Datetime?` does, because it's transformed `Nullable<DateTime>` by compiler.

Comment: Ahhh, I see, I'm starting to learn that there are quite a few differences between `DateTime` and `DateTime?` - thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of having to manually perform a null check every time, you can write an extension method.

```
 public static string ToStringFormat(this DateTime? dt, string format)
 {
      if(dt.HasValue) 
         return dt.Value.ToString(format);
      else
         return "";
 }
```

And use it like this (with whatever string format you want)

```
 Console.WriteLine(myNullableDateTime.ToStringFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: This is the first time I have encountered an extension method. It is perhaps a little overkill for my needs (as this nullable datetime situation is a rare encounter in my application) but your answer is elegant and has been a learning experience for me. Thanks! +1

Comment: @Teifi - You're welcome :) Extension methods must be in a static class (I've created a new static class that contains numerous ext methods and import them into my projects). To make an ext method, it has to be static and has to have the word `this`. The first parameter is the type that will be affected (here it's `DateTime?`) So now, when you have a `DateTime?` object, you can press `.` and it will list the usual methods as well as ext ones. More info here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx Useful for repeated actions on types.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use

```
variableName.Value.ToString(customFormat);
```

Comment: But only if you are very confident that your variable doesn't contain null at that point.

Comment: Yeah well, I assumed that people understands what is a nullable type

Comment: Yeah I can just do a `if (variableName != null)` and this method works just as well. Thank you for the workaround! +1

Comment: I would suggest you to use `variableName.HasValue` as it performs this operation :P

Comment: There's no real difference, it just looks cleaner to me to use built in operations. You can read a little bit more about it here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233882/is-there-any-difference-between-mynullablelong-hasvalue-and-mynullablelong-nu)