# DateTime.Value.ToString(format) gives me 12 hour clock

Tags: c#

An extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809099/no-datetime-tostringstring-overload) question, I am pulling a date from a database and displaying it in a grid.

I have the following code:

```
string date = "";
DateTime? dateSent;    

if (row["DateSent"] != DBNull.Value)
                    dateSent = (DateTime)row["DateSent"];
                else dateSent = null;

date = (dateSent.HasValue ? dateSent.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss") : null);
```

When I add a breakpoint at the end of this block of code, I can see that the `DateTime?` variable "dateSent" has a 24-hour clock timestamp eg 14:50:34. However, when I check the value of the `string` variable "date" - it has a 12-hour clock format eg 02:50:34.

It is not my intention to convert to a 12 hour clock format. I have two questions:

1. Why is dateSent.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss") returning a 12 hour clock timestamp?
2. How can I avoid this and use the 24-hour clock version?

Comment: Take a look at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> Why is dateSent.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss") returning a 12 hour clock timestamp?

Because you're asking for it. That's what `hh` means. `HH` is 24-hour.

When in doubt, read the documentation on [custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

`hh` is documented as

> The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12."

`HH` is documented as:

> The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.

As a further note, this comment suggests a potential conceptual error:

> I can see that the DateTime? variable "dateSent" has a 24-hour clock timestamp eg 14:50:34

A `DateTime` value doesn't *have* a format. It's just a date and time. Just as an `int` with a value of sixteen is both "0x10" and "16" depending on how you format it, the same is true for `DateTime`. There's no format which goes around with the value - the results of just calling `ToString()` will depend on the culture settings.

Comment: @Teifi: See my edit for something else important to note - you should differentiate between the values and any textual representations of them.

Answer (score 11):

It should be as simple as capitalizing your h's

```
HH:mm:ss
```

[Here is a decent link to string formating date times](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

From the article:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);
```

Notice that the hour is 16

```
String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Damn I wish I could accept multiple answers.

Answer (score 6):

Use capital letters for the Hours:

```
HH:mm:ss
^^
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, unfortunately I can't mark every answer as accepted, even though they are all great. +1

Answer (score 5):

If you want to display a 24-hours string use the following [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
HH:mm:ss
```

Hope it helps