# C# HasValue vs !=null

Tags: c#, null

My question might sound a little foolish but it bugs me every time i face it.
What is the difference between :

```
where value.HasValue
```

and

```
where value != null
```

Does HasValue checks if `value` is null?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233882/is-there-any-difference-between-mynullablelong-hasvalue-and-mynullablelong-nu

Answer (score 109, accepted):

They both do the same thing, just pick one and stick with it so that you have consistency. There is nothing to gain by using either in the end.