# whats the difference (if any) between nullable == null and nullable.hasvalue

Tags: c#, nullable

Say I have

```
int? x = SomeFunc();
```

I got into the habit of saying

```
if(x != null && x.HasValue)
{
   // do somethign with x.Value;
}
```

But a code analysis tool headslapped me for doing this saying that the 2 conditions are the same. And I looked and in fact they are

ie if

```
int? x = null;
x==Null; // true
x.HasValue // false
```

So why 2 ways of testing for the same thing? Is there a subtle difference I am missing?

Comment: I think you mean `x.HasValue // false`

Comment: x==Null is wrong by OO concepts but it works as there is an exception for Nullable<T> struct. Otherwise a struct in C# can never be null. so as a summary both work fine, but it's more correct, by Object Oriented definitions, to check HasValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between these two .
it's just matter of convention .

Just pick one (which you like) and stick with it .

Comment: There is no difference between these .Above question already asked by few users on stackoverflow.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783929/c-sharp-hasvalue-vs-null