# Safely and properly pulling value from Nullable?

Tags: c#, syntax, null, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is preferred: Nullable<>.HasValue or Nullable<> == null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676078/which-is-preferred-nullable-hasvalue-or-nullable-null)

I'm working in a codebase which uses both of the following forms for "safely" getting values out of Nullable types.  For example, if `foo` is a Nullable (int?):

```cs
if (foo != null) {
    value = (int)foo;
}

if (foo.HasValue) {
    value = foo.Value;
}
```

I prefer the second form, but is there any particular context which might make the first (or the second, for that matter) certainly preferred over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and second are *exactly* equivalent, and compile down to the same IL.

EDIT: They do indeed generate the same IL, like this:

```
  IL_000b:  ldloca.s   V_1
  IL_000d:  call       instance bool valuetype 
                           [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::get_HasValue()
  IL_0012:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0013:  ceq
  IL_0015:  stloc.2
  IL_0016:  ldloc.2
  IL_0017:  brtrue.s   IL_0023
  IL_0019:  nop
  IL_001a:  ldloca.s   V_1
  IL_001c:  call       instance !0 valuetype
                           [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::get_Value()
  IL_0021:  stloc.0
```

This is guaranteed by section 7.10.9 of the C# 4 spec (or the equivalent in other versions).

Basically - use whichever form you and your team find more readable.

Anton highlighted the [*null-coalescing operator*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) - while Anton's code isn't equivalent to yours, it's an operator that you definitely should be familiar with, as it can really make for nice code.

Comment: Yes, it *is* guaranteed that the compiler will use the Value property, if the compiler conforms with the spec (version 3.0 section 7.9.9, "Equality operators and null").

Comment: @phoog: Good catch. It's section 7.10.9 in the C# 4 spec. Will edit.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use the second form because it represents what a Nullable actually is -- a struct with two members.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer

```
var value = foo ?? 0;
```

Comment: That's not the same though - that will change the value of `value` *even if `foo` is null`, which isn't the case with the code in the question.

Comment: Maybe so, Jon, but you'll get a compile error if `value` is uninitialized before you use it, so might as well make the code more readable by initializing it to the default value like Anton has suggested using the null coalescing operator `??`.