# c# xml serialization doesn't write null

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, null, xml-nil

when I serialize a c# object with a nullable DateTime in it, is there a way to leave the null value out of the xml file instead of having

```
 <EndDate d2p1:nil="true" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `Specified` extended property to leave out null values (or any other value, for that matter).  Basically, create another property with the same name as the serialized property with the word `Specified` added to the end as a boolean.  If the `Specified` property is `true`, then the property it is controlling is serialized.  Otherwise, if it is `false`, the other property is left out of the xml file completely:

```
[XmlElement("EndDate")]
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
[XmlIgnore]
public bool EndDateSpecified { get {
    return (EndDate != null && EndDate.HasValue); } }
```

Comment: Very clever. Thanks!

Is the `[XmlElement("EndDate")]` needed?

Comment: Only one of `EndDate != null` and `EndDate.HasValue` is needed. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/676089/386544)

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable%28VS.85%29.aspx)

this allows you to say whether you want an empty element for null objects

Comment: Actually this won't work because `DateTime` is a value type.  From the documentation you linked: "**Additionally, you cannot set this property to false for nullable value types. When such types are a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic), they will be serialized by setting xsi:nil to true.**"

Comment: good point, I did miss the fact he was dealing with a DateTime, thansk for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but in case someone else find this:

You can also implement a public method for each property to check whether it should be serialized or not. The convention is:

```
bool ShouldSerialize[YourPropertyName]();
```

For example, in your case

```
public bool ShouldSerializeEndDate(){
    return (EndDate != null && EndDate.HasValue);
}
```

Do this for each property you want to optionally serialize.