# resharper custom pattern replacement with negative equality expression

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a rule in resharper to find calls to Nullable.HasValue

```
T? foo; 
//...

if(foo.HasValue)
{}

//And it offers to replace with a comparison directly with null:

if(foo != null)
{}
```

This works great, but when it encounters a negated `.HasValue`, the result is a little strange.

```
if(!foo.HasValue) {}

//is replaced with
if(!(foo != null)) {}
```

Then resharper wants me to simplify the statement to just `if(foo == null)`

```
//ideally it would automatically get to this without the extra step:
if(foo == null) {}
```

The rule is defined as:

```
type:     System.ValueType or derived
nullable: expression of type System.Nullable<$type$>

search pattern:
$nullable$.HasValue

replace pattern:
$nullable$ != null
```

('Format after replace' and 'Shorten references' are both checked)

Is there a way I can write this rule so ReSharper handles it intelligently?  I tried making a second rule for `!$nullable$.HasValue`, but that causes both rules to match which makes tool-tip suggestions look confusing: `replace with == null` and `replace with != null`.

Comment: I don't know a solution. Just an idea and I guess you thought already about it: Remove pattern for `!foo.HasValue` and add only patterns for `foo.HasValue` and `!(foo != null)`. So there is only one rule at a time but unfortunately you need to use **two** consecutive patterns for code like `!foo.HasValue`.

Comment: Search patterns contain only positive rules. I already missed several times the possibility to define negative rules to exclude special code for a pattern.

Comment: Resharper Custom Patterns are quite a pain to work out, I wish there was a test custom pattern engine you could run some known good and known bad expressions against inside there

Answer (score 0):

If is not really mandatory you can give up on this rule because, according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676078/which-is-preferred-nullable-hasvalue-or-nullable-null):

"The compiler replaces null comparisons with a call to HasValue, so there is no real difference. Just do whichever is more readable/makes more sense to you and your colleagues."

Comment: Understood, but my motivation is that I think null comparisons are more readable, and I want resharper to enforce that style decision.