# What is the difference hasvalue operator check for null

Tags: c#, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is preferred: Nullable<>.HasValue or Nullable<> == null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676078/which-is-preferred-nullable-hasvalue-or-nullable-null)

I have field `DateTime? Date`

I need check Date for null and set min value.

```
var anyDate = Date ?? DateTime.MinValue();
```

or

```
var anyDate = Date.HasValue ? Date.Value : DateTime.MinValue();
```

what is right ?

Comment: Both will work, but the semantics of the second are better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this

```
var anyDate = Date.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MinValue);
```

Since you want to check for null and in that case assign a default value, this roughly translates to the form

```
if(Date.HasValue)
   return Date.Value;
return defaultvalue;
```

Answer (score 3):

Both are. First one is shorter and then has my preference.
Check :
[Which is preferred: Nullable<>.HasValue or Nullable<> != null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676078/which-is-preferred-nullable-hasvalue-or-nullable-null)