# F# - Calling a c# method with overloads and params

Tags: f#

No idea how the 30 other articles have managed to not help me here, but I'm working with a c# dll with these overloads:

```
function TqlForBidAskTrade(string, int?, params string[])
function TqlForBidAskTrade(string[], int?, params string[])
```

I can call this method with the params I want in c# like this:

```
TqlForBidAskTrade("string", null)
```

What is the equivalent in F#?  I can't seem to get anything to compile at all.  I've tried:

```
TqlForBidAskTrade("string", null)
TqlForBidAskTrade("string", Nullable<int>())
TqlForBidAskTrade("string", Nullable<int>(), null)
TqlForBidAskTrade("string", Nullable<int>(), [])
TqlForBidAskTrade("string", Nullable<int>(), ["doodah"])
TqlForBidAskTrade("string", 4, ["doodah"])
```

It sure seems like w/ all of the similar requests I should have stumbled across this, but I've been looking for an hour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You found the solution, but to add some explanation:

The C# compiler treats `Nullable<T>` specially. One example is `null` can be substituted for `new Nullable<T>()`. Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/676089/162396).

In F#, `Nullable<'T>` is just another type: no sugar, no magic. `option<'T>` is the closest thing to a `Nullable` counterpart, and is used for [optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx). Your function could look like this, if defined in F#:

```
type T =
  static member TqlForBidAskTrade(s:string, ?n:int, ?args:string[]) = ()

T.TqlForBidAskTrade("foo")
```

Answer (score 5):

and...  face-palm.
TqlForBidAskTrade("string", Nullable()) did work, In my random code tinkering, I'd messed up the syntax.

Comment: Note that `new Nullable<int>()` would also work.  That is, if you add type parameters, you also need to explicitly use `new`.

Comment: @kvb: `Nullable<int>()`—without `new`—works too (or even `Nullable<_>()`).

Comment: @kvb: On further thought, I think you got it switched around: if you use `new` you must supply type args.

Comment: @Daniel - oops, you're absolutely right.  I was basing my comment off of the assumption that the code in the original question didn't work (which seems not to be the case).