# Difference between Nullable types "not having a value" and "being Null" in C#

Tags: c#

What is the difference in the terms

> 1. Not having a value

and

> 2.Being Null

in Nullable types in C#.

In otherwords when do we say a type does not have a value and when do we say the value is null.

Comment: @GrantWinney That does seem to be the question, though I think you have overcomplicated it. `String myStr;` vs `String myStr = null;` would satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Nullable<T>` is a struct, and being a struct, it cannot ever actually be null.  The only actual data stored in a `Nullable<T>` is an underlying value of type `T` and a boolean `HasValue` flag.  A `Nullable<T>` value in which `HasValue` is *false* can be thought of as being `null`, even though it technically is not null.

There is some compiler magic such that `someNullable == null` can be called, and the result of that expression is actually the same as `someNullable.HasValue`.  You can also assign `null` to a `Nullable<T>`.  What this will actually do is create a new `Nullalbe<T>` struct where `HasValue` is `false`.  (Interestingly, it's not possible for you to do that yourself if you were to write your own type.)

There is some more compiler magic such that if you box a `Nullalbe<T>` it doesn't actually box the nullable type.  If `HasValue` is actually true then it will pull out the underlying value and box that.  If `HasValue` is false then it will just box `null`.  When unboxing something to a `Nullable` it then does the reverse; creating a `Nullable<T>` struct based on whether it's null or not.  (This is another thing that you couldn't do with a custom type.)

Because of these special compiler features it does a fairly good job of making it *appear* as if `Nullable` can actually be `null`, but the reality is that it is not *actually* `null`.

Answer (score 2):

A `Nullable<T>` itself cannot be null because its a structure. So you may find a `Nullable<T>` that follow the case: `Not having a value` but it is not null actually.

**EDIT:**

> ---------------------------- **Not Having a Value case**   ------- **Can be null case**
>
> ---
>
> **Reference types** ----(equals to can be null case)-------- Possible
>
> **Value types**------------ Not Possible ---------------------------Not Possible
>
> **Nullable**-----------------Possible --------------------------------Not Possible

Here, the sepration of Nullable and Value types do not mean `Nullable` is not a value type.

Comment: But isn't Nullable<T> itself a non-nullable type?

Comment: @MaxPRafferty He states that in his first sentence.

Comment: @MaxPRafferty `Nullable<T>` is a structure so its a value type and cannot be null itself. however its `Value` member may be null.

Comment: The `Value` of a `Nullable` can *never* be null.  It will always be a struct, and structs can't ever be null, which is the whole reason for having a `Nullable` type in the first place.

Comment: @Servy What about `Nullable<T>.Value`?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad What about it?  It's a struct.  it's non-nullalbe.  If it were nullable, there'd be no reason to use `Nullable` in the first place.  When a `Nullable` value represents `null` the `Value` can have anything; it's garbage data.  Generally it'll have the default value, although it doesn't really matter what bits are in there as it can't be read.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad: The `Value` property of `Nullable<T>` is `T`, which is a value type, so that's not null either. You can compare a `Nullable<T>`to null, but it isn't null (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/676089/593627)).

Comment: Right, but that isn't unique to the Nullable (big N) struct, or any struct, or any non-nullable (little n) type for that matter. It seems unrelated to the question, which is what the difference is between a nullable type "not having a value" and a nullable type being "null".

Answer (score 0):

It's been mentioned that the generic nullable type, `Nullable<T>` (where T must be a value type) has the important properties:

```
bool HasValue // Indicating that a real value is present, or if the instance should be considered null
T Value        // Your value, if present. (non-nullable)
```

So you could conceivably have these cases for a `Nullable<int> myInt`:

```
HasValue  |  Value  |  Represents
------------------------------
false     |   0     | No Value / null
true      |   0     |    0
true      |   3     |    3
```

In the first case, `HasValue` indicates that the `myInt` has no value, and represents the `null` state; a comparison for equality with the null literal will be considered true:

```
(myInt == null) // true.
```

The nullable type itself will not actually be null (it's a struct, it can't be), but the compiler will resolve the the null comparison by querying `HasValue`, as mentioned in one of the other [answers linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676078/which-is-preferred-nullable-hasvalue-or-nullable-null/676089#676089).

Answer (score 0):

If we are discussing terms, let's be clear with language. As many of the other answers have said, in c#, when a non-nullable type is made to be nullable using the `?` operator, it becomes the Nullable struct, where T will always be a value type.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx

see Servy's answer for a good explanation of this.

However, once any type is nullable (regardless of if it is a reference type or has been made to use the Nullable struct) it would be correct to say that if the type has no value, the type is null, and vice versa. From the above Microsoft documentation:

> A type is said to be nullable if it can be assigned a value or can be
>   assigned null, which means the type has no value whatsoever.