# How is it possible for me to call HasValue on a null object?

Tags: c#, variables, exception, nullable

Consider the following code:

```
int? myInt = null;
var hasValue = myInt.HasValue;
```

This is perfectly acceptable, and `HasValue` will return false. But how have I managed to reference a property on an object that is null? The following wouldn't work:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool MyBool { get { return true; } };
}

// Elsewhere in code...
MyClass myObject = null;
myObject.MyBool;
```

This would raise a null reference exception. The fact I'm comparing the two code snippets above as though they are equal tells me that I'm misunderstanding a structure or some syntax somewhere.

**Can somebody please tell me why code snippet 1 does not raise an exception, but why my code snippet 2 would?**

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/676078/1997232). `int? myInt = null;` is a simple *compiler magic* it doesn't means you are : 1) have reference type 2) set it to `null` (you set something else to `null`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first case, you have a value of type `Nullable<int>`, which is "the null value for the type". The `Nullable<T>` type is a value type with two fields, like this:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
{
    private T value;
    private bool hasValue;
}
```

When you use the `null` literal with a `Nullable<T>`, you're really just creating a value where the `value` field has the default value of `T`, and `hasValue` is false. Using the `HasValue` property isn't following a reference - it's just getting a field out of the struct.

In the second case, the value of `myObject` is a null *reference*... so if you try to use the `MyBool` property, that fails because it's trying to find an object when there isn't one.

So the key points are:

- `Nullable<T>` is a struct, not a class
- The value of a variable of type `Nullable<T>` is just a value with two fields, *not* a reference
- The `null` literal just means "the null value of the relevant type", it does *not* always mean a null reference.

Comment: Brilliant Jon, thanks very much (will mark accordingly when it allows me to). I think I'm at the point were I'd benefit from delving deeper into code like you have there for questions like this. How have you got hold of that? Is it reflector?

Comment: @DeeMac: Reflector, the language specification, and MSDN. It sounds like you might benefit from my book, C# in Depth - but no pressure :)