# C# Convert Nullable DateTime in String with mask into Select New

Tags: c#, linq

I must to retry a nullable Datetime from an Entity Framework and convert it in a Masked string of this type: `ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`

I retry all the value with this code(now i show the only DataLead)

```
 var dbResult = conc.Clientes.Where(x => x.StatoCliente == "1").ToList();
                var leads = from e in dbResult
                            select new
                            { 
                              e.DataLead
                            } into selectedLead
                            select selectedLead;
                return Json(leads, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In other part of my code i do the conversion with this code:

```
 DateTime date = (DateTime) DataLead;
 string dateElaborated = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

But, how can i do this operation in my LINQ selection function?

Thanks to all

Comment: Is `e.DataLead` your nullable date?  What do you want to happen if it's null?

Comment: Yes, it's my nullable date. If it's null i can't return an empty string or null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string.Format (suppose e.DateLead is nullable DateTime type):

```
var dbResult = conc.Clientes.Where(x => x.StatoCliente == "1").ToList();
var leads = from e in dbResult
    select new
    {
        Datalead = string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", e.DataLead)
    };
```

Or the new feature in C# 6

```
var leads = from e in dbResult
    select new
    {
        Datalead = e.DataLead?.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var leads = from e in dbResult
            select new {
                selectedLead = e.DataLead != null ? e.DataLead.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"): string.Empty
            };
```

Comment: You are missing the ?

Comment: No, that won't compile.  If not for any other reason as there is no such thing as `nulle`.

Comment: Also, the preferred way to check if a nullable is null is with `HasValue`.

Comment: I have try it but doesn't work. I have an error on ":" - it ask me the }

Comment: Actually scratch what I just said.  Proof: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676078/which-is-preferred-nullable-hasvalue-or-nullable-null

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
// Get alternative text if DataLead is null
var leads = dbResult.Select(entry => entry.DataLead)
                    .Select(date => date.HasValue 
                                    ? date.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") 
                                    : "unknown");

// Get only entries where DataLead is not null.
var leads = dbResult.Select(entry => entry.DataLead)
                    .Where(entry => entry.HasValue)
                    .Select(date => date.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

Comment: Thanks but i use Select New because i need to load a lot of parameters...for simplicity i have write only DataLead, but I have almost 20 dates to be loaded

Answer (score 0):

```
var leads = conc.Clientes
    .Where(o => o.StatoCliente == "1" && o.DataLead.HasValue)
    .Select(o => o.DataLead.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
    .ToList();
```

Simple and clear. Also, I'd strongly advise to not use string literals like `"1"`, but introduce an enum or a const value.

Comment: Thanks but i use Select New because i need to load a lot of parameters...for simplicity i have write only DataLead, 
but I have almost 20 dates to be loaded

Comment: So check all the dates and get their values. And try to be more specific next time.