# Better way to check three properties having some value or all of them are NULL in C#

Tags: c#

There are three properties in the object

```
{obj.prop1, obj.prop2, obj.prop3} These properties are NULLABLE INTEGER
```

And I need to validate either all three properties should contain some value or all three properties are null.

Here's the validation

```
if (!((!obj.prop1.HasValue && !obj.prop2.HasValue && !obj.prop3.HasValue) ||
                (obj.prop1.HasValue && obj.prop2.HasValue && obj.prop3.HasValue)))
{
     //throw new Exception("");
}
```

Is there any better way to do it via some other Logical operators?

Comment: What's wrong with that way?

Comment: `if (obj.prop1.HasValue != obj.prop2.HasValue || obj.prop2.HasValue != obj.prop3.HasValue) throw...`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633286/nullable-types-best-way-to-check-for-null-or-zero-in-c-sharp

Comment: @roryap it looks very puzzled, I would like to know if there's any other logical operator which can make this more readable and understandable for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
if (obj.prop1.HasValue != obj.prop2.HasValue || obj.prop2.HasValue != obj.prop3.HasValue) 
   throw...
```

The expression above yields:

```
p1.HasValue  p2.HasValue  p3.HasValue
==========================================================================
   false        false        false           => false || false => false
   false        false        true            => false || true  => true
   false        true         false           => true  || true  => true
   true         false        false           => true  || false => true
   false        true         true            => true  || false => true
   true         true         false           => false || true  => true
   true         false        true            => true  || true  => true
   true         true         true            => false || false => false
```

Comment: Btw, where did you generate that nice gate chart? Did you made it manually or is there any tool available for that?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7b1e4z6(v=vs.110).aspx). The `.Equals` check for nullable types already checks both `HasValue` and the actual value. So you probably just need `Equals`.

Comment: @ManishRawat, I did it manually. Nice editor allows you to edit multiple lines at once

Comment: @ScottHannen it is not required that values are the same, just that either all have values or none.

Answer (score 1):

You could use null coalescing for the null check, but you would still need to verify if all items do actually have a value for the other:

```
if((obj.prop1 ?? obj.prop2 ?? obj.prop3) == null 
   || (obj.prop1.HasValue && obj.prop2.HasValue && obj.prop3.HasValue)) 
{
   // conditional block
}
```

However, I think the original way you have it is more understandable to an average user.

Comment: Shouldn't the whole block wrapped inside a NOT (!) block?

Comment: I could add that, but I was just showing the usage of the null coalescing operator.

Comment: Yeah, I got the idea what you are mentioning.. have a look at the Zdeslav Vojkovic answer above, that looks awesome.

Comment: Agree, he had already put that in the comments on your question so I didn't want to appear to be sniping his answer, but I wanted to at least provide another option. =)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a logical operator that can make the code look nicer, but what I often do is wrap the functionality in to a method with a name that describes the test. This helps reduce the code size, and makes the code "self documenting".

Here's an example method that will test a bunch of objects to see if they are "partially null".

```
private static bool ArePartiallyNull(params object[] values)
{
    if(values.Length <= 1)
        return false;

    var isNull = values[0] == null;

    for(var i = 1;i < values.Length;i++)
    {
        if(isNull != (values[i] == null))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And this method in action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6QIpDF

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int? one = 1;
        int? two = 1;
        int? three = 1;

        int? nullOne = null;
        int? nullTwo = null;
        int? nullThree = null;

        Console.WriteLine(ArePartiallyNull(one, two, three));
        Console.WriteLine(ArePartiallyNull(nullOne, nullTwo, nullThree));
        Console.WriteLine(ArePartiallyNull(one, two, nullThree));
    }

    private static bool ArePartiallyNull(params object[] values)
    {
        if(values.Length <= 1)
            return false;

        var isNull = values[0] == null;

        for(var i = 1;i < values.Length;i++)
        {
            if(isNull != (values[i] == null))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a handful of ways you can go about this depending on how "automatic" you want it to be when you add new properties for the object. If you don't mind updated your check each time you add a new property, I would just go with a simple method for comparison.

First, the example you have provided is a just fine approach. This is actually going to be the most performant way to perform the check. The downside is it is overly verbose, and doesn't scale well if you plan to add a lot more properties to the object.

The next method you could consider is to create a custom function that compares the properties for you. This way, when you use the function in your code, it is a bit less verbose. The function below will take as many int? variables you want to throw at it, and verify that they all either have a value, or don't have a value.

```
bool Test(params int?[] props) 
{
    bool? lastValue = null;
    foreach(int? p in props) 
    {
        // We haven't got a status yet so we just use the status for the first prop
        if (lastValue.HasValue == false)
            lastValue = p.HasValue;
        else
        {
            // If the status of this next prop doesn't match the first, we know it is false
            if (p.HasValue != lastValue.Value) 
                return false;
        }
    }

    // Default back to true since we didn't identify any issues.
    return true;
}
```

The last option I would propose would be to use reflection. With reflection, you could loop over the properties and check each one using similar logic to the function above. The benefit of this approach is that you do not need to adjust your logic as you add new properties. The downside is performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make sure that all three have a value or don't have a value (regardless of what the value is) then

```
bool AllAreTrueOrFalse(params bool[] values)
{
    return values.All(value=>value) || !values.Any(value=>value);
}

var allTrueOrFalse = AllAreTrueOrFalse(obj.prop1.HasValue, obj.prop2.HasValue, 
    obj.prop3.HasValue);
```