# How to write a LINQ to only get rows that match a certain condition dependant on columns shown?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, logic

I have the following scenario: I need to show a table with 3 columns each having 2 sub-columns and respective values (The DB table contains the sub-columns, grouping is done at UI level):

```
     A     |     B     |     C            <-- column level
-----------|-----------|-----------
  a1 |  a2 |  b1 |  b2 |  c1 |  c2        <-- sub-column level
-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----       Row nr.
  1  |     |     |     |     |             1
     |     |  2  |  0  |     |             2
     |     |     |  0  |  0  |  3          3
     |     |     |     |     |             4
     |     |  0  |     |  0  |             5
 -2  |     |     |  9  |  4  |             6
....
```

I have to write a query which returns **IQueryable** and which holds the following logic:

1. There is a boolean flag in the UI which tells me which COLUMN should be visible on screen (e.g. *ShowA*, *ShowB*, *ShowC*), based on user selection. Any combination is possible or none at all (*A+B+C, A+B, A+C, B+C, A, B, C, none*)
2. If **any ROW** contains only ZEROS (0) or NULLS for **visible columns only**, do not display that row, keeping in mind the visibility of the columns, so only for visible columns. (e.g. row 4 and 5 should not be visible in the UI)

I come up with something like this, but it only shows rows which have all columns NON-ZERO or NOT NULL:

```
if (showA)
{
  model.List = model.List.Where(x => (x.a1 != null && x.a1 != 0) || (x.a2 != null && x.a2 != 0));
}
if (showB)
{
  model.List = model.List.Where(x => (x.b1 != null && x.b1 != 0) || (x.b2 != null && x.b2 != 0));
}
if (showC)
{
  model.List = model.List.Where(x => (x.c1 != null && x.c1 != 0) || (x.c2 != null && x.c2 != 0));
}
```

Comment: sub-columns in db table? what is that?

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. Updated

Comment: The problem is that you ultimately want all of those separate conditions or'ed but when you do consecutive `Where` calls it's and'ing the conditions.  You'll have to build up one condition for one `Where` call.

Comment: I know. That's where the confusion is..

Comment: I think the real issue is you can't fill the tables with nulls.  So you may be able to fix problem by making sure when you fill the table that you replace nulls with string.Empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
model.List = model.List.Where(x =>
    showA && ((x.a1 ?? 0) != 0 || (x.a2 ?? 0) != 0) ||
    showB && ((x.b1 ?? 0) != 0 || (x.b2 ?? 0) != 0) ||
    showC && ((x.c1 ?? 0) != 0 || (x.c2 ?? 0) != 0));
```

Comment: Can also use `(x.a1 ?? 0) != 0` instead of `x.a1 != null && x.a1 != 0` for short. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/633294/5690722)

Comment: Great idea! Updated my answer.

Comment: We need more brackets!

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a simplified logic:

```
return model.List.Where(x =>
    (showA && ((x.a1 ?? 0) != 0)) ||
    (showA && ((x.a2 ?? 0) != 0)) ||
    (showB && ((x.b1 ?? 0) != 0)) ||
    (showB && ((x.b2 ?? 0) != 0)) ||
    (showC && ((x.c1 ?? 0) != 0)) ||
    (showC && ((x.c2 ?? 0) != 0))
).ToList();
```

Any `show...` with any (relevant, non-null-or-0 value) "sub-column" should yield the row.

Answer (score -1):

How I see it is that you need a model representation for a row. 
F.e. list which will keep 6 objects (a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2), then each object should have properties like "column visibility (bool)" and "value (int or whatever you want). Then you will have a clear and separate logic. So, you can check all values in a row and make a decision about visibility. Just try to divide your complex task on few sub-tasks.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
model.List = model.List.Where(x => showA && (Convert.ToInt32(a1) + Convert.ToInt32(a2)) != 0  || showB && (Convert.ToInt32(b1) + Convert.ToInt32(b2)) != || showC && (Convert.ToInt32(c1) + Convert.ToInt32(c2)) != );
```

Comment: First what do you think will happen when one of the columns is `null`?  Second this would still ultimately and the separate conditions together when the whole issue is that they need to be or'ed.

Comment: 1.Convert.ToInt32(null) =0

Comment: 2. i didnt understand question, if you want use all bool params you can  combine it to one query

Comment: If you do `.Where(x => x > 1).Where(x => x <5)` that's the same as `Where(x =>  x > 1 && x < 5)`.  The conditions get anded.  So if `showA` and `showB` are both true then your condition will end up being column A is not null or 0 **AND** column B is not null or zero, but the OP want column A is not null or 0 **OR** column B is not null or zero.

Comment: Also the OP wanted != 0.  They didn't mention if negative values are possible.

Comment: Also remember this is getting turned into SQL, so `Conver.ToInt32` might not do what you think if it's even supported by EF at all.  Not to mention that this values are likely nullable ints anyway, so converting doesn't really make sense.